# Correct way to maintain a company-wide POM

Tags: maven

I have created a company-wide POM that all my projects extend. It contains, apart from the company name and all the little details, actual configuration on where to get artifacts from (repositories configs) and where to deploy to (distributionManagement). This POM got installed in the company repo. The problem now is that the info on where to get the company pom is in the pom itself so i have to manually install the company pom the very first time so that projects can extend it and pull other dependencies from the company repo. Is there any smart way to avoid this problem? *i don't want to configure the repositories in `settings.xml`* since i want other users to just be able to checkout the projects and receive the configuration implicitly.

Apart from the manual install the first time, every time the company pom changes and i want a project to inherit the new version of the pom, i again have to manually download the pom from the repo and install it.

Is there any recommendation on how to do this or has anyone found a nice workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that this just doesn't work. Each user needs to configure the repository in settings.xml; otherwise the information of where to get artifacts is in the same location to get the artifacts so it creates a chicken and egg problem.

What I did leave in the company pom was all the `distributionManagement` configuration and the user-friendly text. Not as useful as before, it makes me even wonder the point of a company pom since i can't really centralize the info, but anyway..

Answer (score 1):

How about the [Maven SCM Plugin `scm:bootstrap`](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/examples/bootstrapping-with-pom.html) goal?

Comment: I don't get it. Can you elaborate. Are you suggesting to have every POM extending the company pom to contain a bootstrapping to checkout the company pom and install it in the local repo??